# Show that the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Show that the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$ is Lebesgue integrable.

I've shown that it isn't Reimann integrable, but I'm stuck on showing it is Lebesgue integrable.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The standard argument is that this function is 0 almost everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

You have that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, so you can write $\mathbb{Q}=\bigcup_{n\geq 0}\{x_n\}.$ As a countable union of borelians sets, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a borelian set and so $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Q}$ is mesurable : by definition $$\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Q}\,d\mu=\mu(\mathbb{Q})=\sum_{n\geq 0}\mu(\{x_n\})=\sum_{n\geq0}0=0.$$

Comment: That's the easiest way. I would personally go with this one as well..

Answer (score 1):

You have to check that the preimages of open semilines $(a,\infty)$ are measurable. As the function takes only two values, the only possible preimages are $\emptyset$, $\mathbb Q$, and $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, but one usually checks only on sets $(a,\infty)$. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Open semilines?  I'm not familiar with that phrase.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Baloown: No worries.

Comment: @DesperateFluffy: because taking pre-image behaves nicely with all set operations, and because the measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra, if $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is measurable for all $a\in\mathbb R$, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is measurable for any open set $V$. It is the basic technique one needs to prove that anything but the most basic functions are measurable.